# trigger a function when changes in the DB are being commited

Tags: sql, database, triggers, chat

I was always wondering if it's possible to create a block of code (probably php code) that will execute when a certain change is being committed to the database.

For instance, chat application. When a user sends a message, it will add a message to a table, then I would like to force all of the other users to an AJAX request to read this new value (rather than sending AJAX request every 100ms to check if there is a new message)

I remember something that involved node.js and some other type of DB rather than mysql. If this is the only solution, can it work along with a normal mysql database?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you not make a `Trigger` that called a `function`?

Comment: @Siyual I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: If you are looking for something that executes when tables are `Updated`, `Inserted`, or `Deleted`, then that's a `Trigger`.  If you're wanting to run a `function`, could you not just run it from inside the `trigger`?

Comment: @fancyPants I edited the question. Hopefully you can understand now

Comment: @Siyual How can I do that? How do I add a `Trigger` to a table that will execute a PHP function?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, MySQL supports [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html), but they are pretty much limited to do other data operations. So you'd still have to get some notification sent to your javascript client

A better way of doing client notifications with with [websocket](/questions/tagged/websocket) or [comet](/questions/tagged/comet), allowing the server to push notifications from a [message-queue](/questions/tagged/message-queue).

You didn't give much detail about your programming environment, so I'll leave it to you to follow the tag links I gave above, and research the appropriate tools and frameworks for using these general methods.

---

Re your comment:

- For PHP, here's an example "push" chat application: 
  http://www.aljtmedia.com/blog/websockets-for-php-ratchet-push-chat-application/
- Here's an primer on using message queues in general:
  http://blog.thecodepath.com/2013/01/06/asynchronous-processing-in-web-applications-part-2-developers-need-to-understand-message-queues/
- And here are tutorials for RabbitMQ (one simple option among many MQ solutions usable by PHP), including PHP examples: https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html

Comment: well, I was talking about PHP and MySQL. I will definitely read about websocket and comet :) Thanks!